# How to find Volumetric Expansion if not given the volumetric coefficient?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I'm doing a few practice questions on thermodynamics to prepare for my exams next year and I have been stuck with this question ever since. I tried to move on to answer other questions and came back to this one in hopes of having to see it in a different perspective, but no luck. I used this formula

> Volumetric Expansion: $$ \Delta V=V_0 3\alpha \Delta T \tag{1} $$
>   Note: the volumtric expansion coefficient is also given the symbol: $\beta$

Question:
A fixed quantity of an ideal gas is held in a cylinder with a moveable piston which is weighted down to produce a fixed pressure in the gas. The initial volume of the gas is $5.0 × 10^{−3}\ \text{m}^3$. The temperature of the gas is changed from $40\ ^{\circ} \text{C}$ to $80\ ^{\circ} \text{C}$. What is the new volume (in $\text{m}^3$)?

Comment: It's an ideal gas under constant pressure, so use Charles's law.

Comment: use the ideal gas law relations, starting with PV = nRT

Comment: Thank you everyone! I've got the answer using the PV/T = PV/T equation. Then cancelling P on both sides which gave me the V/T = V/T equation. Then I solved for V.